# CAML Query for Date Range - Not Working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml

Hey guys I am trying to get a list of items with a "Created" date range.  The problem is that upon executing the query it seems to be completely ignoring the 5000 row limit.

```
<View Scope='Recursive'>
<Query>
<Where>
<And>
<Geq>
<FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value Type='DateTime'>2000-1-1</Value>
</Geq>
<Leq>
<FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value Type='DateTime'>2001-1-1</Value>
</Leq>
</And>
</Where>
</Query>
<RowLimit>5000</RowLimit>
</View>
```

If I delete the tags inside the Query Tag it then limits the rows to 5000.  This is pretty strange and I don't understand why this is happening with my CAML query.

Comment: Are you sure that the other parts of the CAML is correct though? Do you get results if you remove the RowLimit tag?

Comment: I used U2U in order to create my query.  It should be just fine as it returned results in that application.

Answer (score 1):

The dates look malformed, you need to use ISO format: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime()` in all your date time value so that your CAML query would work. for usage instruction see this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime%28v=office.14%29.aspx)