# PowerShell, Adding List Items, How do i declare a date/time?, and other issues

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, custom-list, 2016, import

I got some solid help on here before with working with PowerShell and SharePoint. While I would consider myself an experienced SysAdmin and a Knowledgeable SharePoint Admin (front-end, Workflow Design, General Admin) - I am a bit of a n00b at the PowerShell side of things. Could I request some help? I am a fast learner!

So I have this script that creates an item in a list from a CSV File, for each row in the file etc. I have got it 90% working. However, how do I declare a Date/Time Field? I am also having some strange issues with a column that is set to a person/group at the list level(error message below)

I have commented out the items in which have errors

here is the script in full:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
$file = Import-Csv -LiteralPath "C:\Users\SPFarm\Desktop\OldMMFExport-CreatedOnAxxia.CSV"
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://SERVERNAME/Site/SubSite/AnotherSubSite/"
$list = $web.Lists["MMFImportTest"]
ForEach ($row in $file) {
    $item = $list.Items.Add()
    $item["Imported"] = $row.Imported
    $item["Form Status"] = "File is Active"
    $item["Legacy Item ID"] = $row."Legacy Item ID"
    $item["Legacy Created By"] = $row."Legacy Created By"
#$item["Legacy Created Date"] = $row."Legacy Created Date
    $item["Status of form when brought over"] = $row."Status of form when brought over"
    $item["Client Number"] = $row."Client Number"
    $item["Client Name"] = $row."Client Name"
    $item["Proposed Matter Name"] = $row."Proposed Matter Name"
    $item["Does Interaction have up to date contact details for the person providing instructions?"] = $row."Does Interaction have up to date contact details for the person providing instructions?"
    $item["Have we agreed a non-standard client charge out rate for this matter?"] = $row."Have we agreed a non-standard client charge out rate for this matter?"
    $item["Please detail and state if these rates to be applied as a rule on Axxia?"] = $row."Please detail and state if these rates to be applied as a rule on Axxia?"
    $item["What is the estimated fee for this matter?:"] = $row."What is the estimated fee for this matter?"
    $item["Did you consult with a(nother) partner on the proposed fee in advance of quoting?"] = $row."Did you consult with a(nother) partner on the proposed fee in advance of quoting?"
    $item["NA Reason"] = $row."NA Reason"
    $item["Please Explain Other Reason"] = $row."Please Explain Other Reason"
#$item["What is the estimated completion date for this matter?"] = $row."What is the estimated completion date for this matter?"
    $item["Is this matter part of a large volume project?"] = $row."Is this matter part of a large volume project?"
    $item["If this matter involves cross departmental coordination, has a project lead been nominated and a project plan drafted?"] = $row."If this matter involves cross departmental coordination, has a project lead been nominated and a project plan drafted?"
    $item["Is the Account Payable information different from the Client File for this New Matter?"] = $row."Is the Account Payable information different from the Client File for this New Matter?"
    $item["Accounts Payable Contact Name"] = $row."Accounts Payable Contact Name"
    $item["Accounts Payable Billing Address"] = $row."Accounts Payable Billing Address"
    $item["Does the client have a PO Reference to be used?"] = $row."Does the client have a PO Reference to be used?"
    $item["Client PO Reference"] = $row."Client PO Reference"
    $item["Please provide DMS document number for Letter of Engagement to the client"] = $row."Please provide DMS document number for Letter of Engagement to the client"
    $item["Do the BW standard terms and conditions apply?"] = $row."Do the BW standard terms and conditions apply?"
    $item["Please Provide Details"] = $row."Please Provide Details"
    $item["Is the Partner responsible for supervising the matter the same as the Fee Earner?"] = $row."Is the Partner responsible for supervising the matter the same as the Fee Earner?"
## CHECK THIS ONE: $item["Fee Earner responsible for day to day file handling"] = $row."Fee Earner responsible for day to day file handling"
## CHECK THIS ONE: $item["Partner responsible for supervising the matter"] = $row."Partner responsible for supervising the matter"
    $item["Is the partner approving different than the supervising partner?"] = $row."Is the partner approving different than the supervising partner?"
    $item["Partner Approving Matter Inception"] = $row."Partner Approving Matter Inception"
    $item["Has Part One Been Completed"] = $row."Has Part One Been Completed"
    $item["Have you completed a conflict search per the firm's conflict checking Policy?"] = $row."Have you completed a conflict search per the firm's conflict checking Policy?"
    $item["Is there any apparent conflict of interest in acting for the client on this matter?"] = $row."Is there any apparent conflict of interest in acting for the client on this matter?"
    $item["If there is apparent conflict, how it can be managed?"] = $row."If there is apparent conflict, how it can be managed?"
    $item["If there is apparent conflict, have we advised the client?"] = $row."If there is apparent conflict, have we advised the client?"
    $item["If there is apparent conflict, has the client given proper authorisation to proceed to act?"] = $row."If there is apparent conflict, has the client given proper authorisation to proceed to act?"
    $item["Chinese Walls Required?"] = $row."Chinese Walls Required?"
    $item["Please Specify the details of the Chinese Walls required"] = $row."Please Specify the details of the Chinese Walls required"
    $item["Have you issued ByrneWallace Terms of Business to the Client?"] = $row."Have you issued ByrneWallace Terms of Business to the Client?"
    $item["Have you verified that this matter is covered by Service Level Agreement or matter engagement?"] = $row."Have you verified that this matter is covered by Service Level Agreement or matter engagement?"
    $item["Is the scope of the work we proposed to undertake adequately defined?"] = $row."Is the scope of the work we proposed to undertake adequately defined?"
    $item["Have you issued the Letter of Engagement to the client?"] = $row."Have you issued the Letter of Engagement to the client?"
    $item["Have you checked that the Firm has requisite client documentation on file to satisfy Anti-Money Laundering regulations?"] = $row."Have you checked that the Firm has requisite client documentation on file to satisfy Anti-Money Laundering regulations?"
    $item["Have you requested the requisite identity documentation from the client where it is not currently on file for the client?"] = $row."Have you requested the requisite identity documentation from the client where it is not currently on file for the client?"
    $item["With reference to the Firm's Risk Assessment Checklist, have you considered all generic risks of taking on this work?"] = $row."With reference to the Firm's Risk Assessment Checklist, have you considered all generic risks of taking on this work?"
    $item["With reference to the Firm's Risk Assessment Checklist, are there any higher or unusual risks of taking on this work?"] = $row."With reference to the Firm's Risk Assessment Checklist, are there any higher or unusual risks of taking on this work?"
    $item["Provide higher risk additional details"] = $row."Provide higher risk additional details"
    $item["Does the engagement include limitation of liability for the firm at €1.5m?"] = $row."Does the engagement include limitation of liability for the firm at €1.5m?"
    $item["Specify reason and amount of limitation"] = $row."Specify reason and amount of limitation"
    $item["I sign as Fee Earner"] = $row."I sign as Fee Earner"
    $item["Ongoing Risk Assesment Completed?"] = $row."Ongoing Risk Assesment Completed?"
    $item["With reference to the Firm's Risk Assessment Checklist, have you considered all generic risks of continuing this work?"] = $row."With reference to the Firm's Risk Assessment Checklist, have you considered all generic risks of continuing this work?"
    $item["With reference to the Firm's Risk Assessment Checklist, are there any higher or unusual risks of continuing this work"] = $row."With reference to the Firm's Risk Assessment Checklist, are there any higher or unusual risks of continuing this work"
    $item["Detail high or unusual risks of continuing this work"] = $row."Detail high or unusual risks of continuing this work"
    $item["I sign ongoing risk as Fee Earner"] = $row."I sign ongoing risk as Fee Earner"
    $item["Nominate Partner responsible for supervising ongoing risk"] = $row."Nominate Partner responsible for supervising ongoing risk"
    $item["I sign ongoing risk as Partner"] = $row."I sign ongoing risk as Partner"
    $item["Fee Earner Signature"] = $row."Fee Earner Signature"
#$item["Date Partner signed"] = $row."Date Partner signed"
    $item["Partner Signature"] = $row."Partner Signature"
#$item["Date Fee Earner signed"] = $row."Date Fee Earner signed"
#$item["Date Created on Axxia"] = $row."Date Created on Axxia"
    $item["Ongoing Risk Assessment Fee Earner signature"] = $row."Ongoing Risk Assessment Fee Earner signature"
#$item["Ongoing Risk Assessment Date signed"] = $row."Ongoing Risk Assessment Date signed"
    $item["Ongoing Risk Assessment Supervising Partner signature"] = $row."Ongoing Risk Assessment Supervising Partner signature"
    $item["Ongoing Risk Assessment Date Supervising Partner signed"] = $row."Ongoing Risk Assessment Date Supervising Partner signed"
    $item.Update()
}
```

For all Colums that are set to Date/Time Fields:

```
$item["Date Partner signed"] = $row."Date Partner signed"
$item["Date Fee Earner signed"] = $row."Date Fee Earner signed"
$item["Date Created on Axxia"] = $row."Date Created on Axxia"
$item["Ongoing Risk Assessment Date signed"] = $row."Ongoing Risk Assessment Date signed"
$item["Legacy Created Date"] = $row."Legacy Created Date
$item["What is the estimated completion date for this matter?"] = $row."What is the estimated completion date for this matter?"
$item["Legacy Created Date"] = $row."Legacy Created Date"
```

I get this error message:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
At line:11 char:5
+     $item["Legacy Created Date"] = $row."Legacy Created Date"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.FormatException
```

This is an example of format of the Date Field within the CSV: 13/09/2017  15:26:00 (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss)

It also seems to have an issue with these columns, that are set to people/group:

```
$item["Fee Earner responsible for day to day file handling"] = $row."Fee Earner responsible for day to day file handling"
$item["Partner responsible for supervising the matter"] = $row."Partner responsible for supervising the matter"
```

I get this error message:

```
Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only."
At line:75 char:5
+     $item.Update()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException
```

When I comment out those particular snippets above, the code runs fine and starts adding items to the list, though, at random times throughout the script running, I get this error message:

```
Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only."
At line:75 char:5
+     $item.Update()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException
```

It's much the same as the one that was mentioned previously for the people/group columns above, except this time the code is running and I cannot pinpoint the particular item in which I need to troubleshoot.

All help/guidance much appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 1):

the date format is typically the [ISO format 8601](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime.aspx) `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ`

(the above page documentation is actually wrong as it states minutes twice)

e.g.

```
(get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ")
```

output

```
2017-10-11T11:56:53Z
```

to convert a specific date string,

```
[datetime]::parseexact('01-Jul-16', 'dd-MMM-yy', $null).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ')
```

For parsing users, you may need [EnsureUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

See More:

[Powershell; copy list item across site collection with people picker fields](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/196564/powershell-copy-list-item-across-site-collection-with-people-picker-fields)

[Error handling in ensureuser() method](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177575/error-handling-in-ensureuser-method)

[CAML Query for Date Range - Not Working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69393/caml-query-for-date-range-not-working/69399#69399)

**update:**

based on your settings, you need something like:

```
[datetime]::parseexact('13/09/2017 15:26:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ')
```

or, using your $row variable, full line for assignment,

```
$item["Legacy Created Date"] = [datetime]::parseexact($row."Legacy Created Date", 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ')
```

based on my findings, your problem was due to **having a 24h clock**.
you have to map the hour with **HH** instead of **hh**, otherwise it will effectivelly throw,

> Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not
>   recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: Cool, thanks - but how do I apply that to my code? - I am getting date/time information from a CSV file and it's been added to a date/time field in SharePoint.

Comment: I guess you have 2 options. either "fix" the csv to be compliant with that format (2017-10-11T11:56:53Z), or you parse the cell value into a DateTime valid format and then use tostring like above to convert it to the ISO format. example added

Comment: Thanks, I do appreciate your help. Your talking to a complete n00b on Powershell, so you need to handhold me through it, looking at my code specifically, where do I need to insert that snippet you gave an example of to parse the date/time form the csv? do i then need to change the code for adding the item from the file in to the list?

Comment: you can start by giving us an example of how your date string looks and what format it is in (e.g. year month day, month day year, etc)

Comment: Thanks, The example of the date string is in my original explanation set out above, this is how it looks in the CSV: This is an example of format of the Date Field within the CSV: 13/09/2017 15:26:00 (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss) This is the code i am using to import $item["Legacy Created Date"] = $row."Legacy Created Date"

Comment: answer updated. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for all your help, that seems to be moving things along, but, i am getting that same error you mentioned above and i have the corrected hh to HH. orEach ($row in $file) {
    $item = $list.Items.Add()
    $item["Legacy Created Date"] = [datetime]::parseexact($row."Legacy Created Date", 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") error: Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: well you'll have to make sure that all your rows contain a valid date as per the pattern you are setting (dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss). if one of the rows dont follow the pattern or is empty, you may get an exception. try using Write-host ($row."Legacy Created Date") just before the assignment so that you output what is being converted. if it fails there, try to convert that line independently on a shell to find out the problem

Comment: btw you probably have other date fields so you really have to start adding some outputs and double checking the specific line where you got the exception. write-host, read-host (to pause the script) are your best friends.